# Magento2 custom javascript moving to end of the page while added in head

Tags: magento2

I've added some scripts in head tag using

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_script_block" template="Magento_Theme::script/code.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

All the scripts have moved at the end of page after . But the html comments are in the head tag which has in the code.phtml

Anyone knows it why?

Answer (score 0):

Create default_head_blocks.xml in your theme :

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: I need to add it in within <head> tag.

Comment: Do you want to add js in all pages ? are you used javascript link or added js in folder ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need to add gtag code in head tag. But it's moving to end. You can see it here https://bit.ly/2H3e713

Comment: I have updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code its working for me for gtag:

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="ga_script">
        <action method="setText">
            <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                <![CDATA[
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
                    </script>
                ]]>
             </argument>
        </action>
     </block>
</referenceBlock>
```